# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `input` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: react-native

```
    This is my InputItems.js
    
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from "react-native-web";
    
    function InputItems(props) {
      const [inputGoal, setinputGoal] = useState("");
      return (
        <View style={style.wholeInputcontainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter the Text"
            style={style.textInput}
            onChangeText={(enteredtext) => {
              setinputGoal(enteredtext);
            }}
            value={inputGoal}
          />
          <Button title="Submit" onPress={props.onpressprop.bind(this,inputGoal)} />
        </View>
      );
    }
    const style = StyleSheet.create({
      wholeInputcontainer: {
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      },
      textInput: {
        borderBottomColor: "blue",
        borderBottomWidth: 4,
        marginBottom: 10,
        width: 300,
      },
    });
    
    export default InputItems;

and this is my App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import Listitems from "./Components/ListItems";
import InputItems from "./Components/InputItems";
// import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-web';

export default function App() {
  const [outputGoal, setoutputGoal] = useState([]);
  const Onpress = (InputGoalProp) => {
    setoutputGoal((Currentgoal) => [...Currentgoal, InputGoalProp]);
  };
  return (
    <View style={style.root}>
      <InputItems onpressprop={Onpress} />
      {/* We can use mapping from outputGoal but using FlatList instead of ScrollView is more efficient */}
      <FlatList
        data={outputGoal}
        renderItem={(listitems) => <Listitems anything={listitems.item} />}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  //StyleSheet is a class of react-native, we can always use inline styleing
  root: {
    marginTop: 100,
  },
});
```

Stuck into this problem. Please help me if you can.
This is the error...

Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `input` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
in input (created by TextInput)
in TextInput (created by InputItems)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this line:

`<Button title="Submit" onPress={props.onpressprop.bind(this,inputGoal)} />`

There's a comma instead of a period after `this`. It should be

`<Button title="Submit" onPress={props.onpressprop.bind(this.inputGoal)} />`

Answer (score 0):

In `InputItems.js` you still have the wrong import (seems like you have already corrected it in `App.js`):

change this: `import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from "react-native-web";`

to: `import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";`